# Passar variável de um controller para um service

Tags: angularjs, api

```js
angular.module('myApp').controller('paginasCtrl', function($scope, CarregaItens) {

  function carregaPaginas () {
      CarregaItens.getPaginas()
      .success(function (data) {
        $scope.paginas = data;
      })
  };

  carregaPaginas();
 
});


.service('CarregaItens', function ($http) {

  getInfoPage = function () {
    return $http.get("http://www.meusite.com.br/api/paginas.php?id=4");
  };

  return {
    getPaginas: getInfoPage
  }

});
```

```html
<div class="col col-50 shop-product-narrow-card" ng-repeat="item in paginas" ui-sref="app.detalhes({id: item.id})">
 <div class="list card">
   <div class="item item-image">
     <pre-img ratio="_1_1" helper-class="main-image">
       <img ng-src="http://www.meusite.com.br/img/paginas/{{item.imagem}}" spinner-on-load>
     </pre-img>
   </div>
   <div class="item item-body">
     <h2 class="card-title">{{item.titulo}}</h2>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Pessoal, tenho esse controller e esse service que interagem perfeitamente bem, mas o que preciso é que o item.id que esta sendo listado na view seja enviado para meu service substituindo o "4" estático da url da API. Já tentei utilizar $routeparams mas ao injetá-lo no controller ele para de funcionar.

Meu raciocínio seria pra algo do tipo

```
return $http.get("http://www.meusite.com.br/api/paginas.php?id=" + id);
```

Mas não funciona (lógico). Alguma idéia?

Comment: Exatamente o q eu precisava!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deverás importar o `$stateParams` e usar o `$stateParams.id`.
Também no `$http.get()` deverás usar o objeto `config` para ficar como mostrado abaixo. Dessa forma irá funcionar

```
return $http.get("http://www.meusite.com.br/api/paginas.php", { 
  params: {
    tipo: 'pagina', 
    user: '4', 
    id: $stateParams.id
  }
});
```

Espero que funcione

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver utilizando o ngRoute, você pode injetar o "$routeParams" no controller (acredito que não é possível utilizar "$routeParams" no service, por isto esta dando erro) e passar o Id como parâmetro no serviço. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('paginasCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, CarregaItens) {

  function carregaPaginas () {
      CarregaItens.getPaginas($routeParams.id)
      .success(function (data) {
        $scope.paginas = data;
      })
  };

  carregaPaginas();

});

.service('CarregaItens', function ($http) {

  getInfoPage = function (id) {
    return $http.get("http://www.meusite.com.br/api/paginas.php?id=" + id);
  };

  return {
    getPaginas: getInfoPage
  }

});
```